# How to assign labels and features when uploading a CSV data file into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I am loading a CSV file into a Pandas dataframe for a Machine Learning project. I have 16 columns. The "label" or "target" is the last column. The rest are variables. I need to define the first 15 columns as features and the 16th as a target.

All examples I find seem to demonstrate Machine Learning on a set that already has those defined. How can I define my "target" myself?

```
import pandas as pd   
import numpy as np    
import sklearn   
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
lymph = pd.read_csv("D:\\dataset_10_lymph.csv", encoding="utf-8", header = 0)

array = lymph.values
data = array[:,0:-1]
target = array[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(lymph.data, lymph.target, stratify=lymph.target, random_state=66)
```

But when I try to test that my target array is generated properly I get a traceback.

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'

It seems like it would be a trivial step one would have to take unless they are using a practice sklearn dataset. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well I got it to work with:

```
    target = lymph.columns[-1]
    X = lymph.drop(target, axis = 1)
    y = lymph.drop(X, axis = 1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
lymph = pd.read_csv("D:\\dataset_10_lymph.csv", encoding="utf-8", header = 0)
```

will give you a DataFrame with column names in numbers. So subsequent `lymph.data` will not find a column named `data` and give you Traceback.

You can assign column names like this:

```
lymph.columns = [....]
```

with the list a list of 16 strings, as you said there are 16 columns. Then you should use those column names in the function call `train_test_split()`. However, as you said the first 15 columns are input and 16th the label. So the label one is easy but the input features is simply the DataFrame with the 16th column dropped. So do this instead:

```
train_test_split(lymph.drop("target", axis=1), lymph.target, stratify=lymph.target, random_state=66)
```

where `"target"` is the name of your 16th column.

Comment: Thank you for your response @adrtam. I'm not sure what you are suggesting. If I use: print(target), it actually prints 16th column values. But it doesn't consider it an object when I call it when I'm trying to split my set with train_test_split. How do I define the last column to be a target object so that I can use all the ML programs that work on datasets with predefines "data" and "target" objects?

Comment: So I got rid of "header = 0" and added "data = lymph.columns[0:-1], target = lymph.columns[-1]" when I print target and data it prints the corresponding column headers. but when I use your train_test_split I still get "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'target'". I just feel like there are 100 examples that use sklearn data sets where target and data objects are predefined. It seems like such an obvious question to ask "Well if I upload my own CSV file, how do I define those so that I can use all of the existing code out there". I have searched and tried many different things to no avail.